# SSRS - Display a text based on first row value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to write an expression, If the result-set's first row values is equal to 1 then display a text. I am not sure how to get first rows value. Can someone help me out to achieve the same.

```
=IIF(Fields!IsAccessAvailable.Value=1, "You have full access to this page","")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IIF(First(Fields!IsAccessAvailable.Value, "YourDatasetName")="1",You have full access to this page","")
```

You could also add the same expression as Textbox Visibility, so that if Fields!IsAccessAvailable.Value = 1 then and then only this textbox will be shown else it will hide it.